# How to close a letter with "Thanking you"?

Tags: punctuation

When we write "Thanking you" at the end of a letter do we put a comma after it before writing other things like "Yours sincerely" and name because "Yours sincerely" is followed by a comma? I am confused because if I write:

```
Thanking you,
Yours sincerely,
Name
```

does it mean that I am thanking myself because in normal English "Thank you" is followed by the name of the person we want to thank?

Does putting or not putting a comma after "Thanking you" make a difference to the meaning conveyed?

Comment: I would put a comma there because it separates two different phrases - and, no, it doesn't mean that you are thanking yourself.

Comment: I would not sign off twice, but make 'thank you' the explicit subject of a paragraph, because that presumably is the reason for the letter.

Comment: You can also decide on your own style, for example omitting commas after your address lines and sign-off lines. Many official letters do. As long as your address is clear and you're consistent, it's your choice: https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-use-commas-in-addresses-and-dates/

Answer (score 3):

Like WeatherVane I wouldn't add an extra sign-off.

I wouldn't use "Thanking you" as a sign-off at all, actually, but in a less formal communication I might use "Thanks" or "Many thanks" or "Thank you" as a sign-off (with a following comma).  (This would then replace rather than supplement "Yours sincerely".)

In a formal letter, instead of having a thank-you as a sign-off, I'd put something like "Thank you very much for any assistance you can provide", "Thank you in advance" (for help not yet given), "Thank you very much for all your help", "Once again, I am grateful for your assistance", "Thank you once again", or "Once again, thank you very much" (followed by a full stop, not a comma) as a complete sentence at the end of the letter (but before "Yours sincerely").  I would probably only use the "once again" versions if I had also thanked them at the start of the letter.